# Need to generate reports using serenity bdd in my selenium cucumber project

Tags: maven, cucumber, serenity-bdd

I have an existing selenium maven cucumber project in sts. My project is using Paige object model with cucumber dependencies I need to incorporate serenity bdd to generate reports for this project. Can someone explain to me how to get my reports generated?

What dependencies do I need, what plug-in do I need and do I need a separate properties file to add in the settings for the reports? Also where do the reports show up and how can I run them?

This is what I have so far:

```
<serenity.version>1.9.17</serenity.version>
<serenity.maven.version>1.9.16</serenity.maven.version>
<serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.7</serenity.cucumber.version>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.13-beta-2</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.6</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit --> 
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.6</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting --> 
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/… --> 
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin --> 
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
   <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java --> 
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit --> 
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.6</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps --> 
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.6</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
   <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
   <version>${serenity.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
   <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
   <version>${serenity.version}</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
   <artifactId>serenity-screenplay</artifactId>
   <version>${serenity.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
   <artifactId>serenity-screenplay-webdriver</artifactId>
   <version>${serenity.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
   <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
   <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
</dependency>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.20</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
   <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>serenity-reports</id>
         <id>serenity-reports</id>
         <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>aggregate</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Let me know if anyone can help, I can post my existing pom.xml

Comment: yes you must have to post in question what you have try already and where you stuck or where you getting problem because here in stackoverflow you can't tutorial how to do so and so

Comment: <serenity.version>1.9.17</serenity.version>
  <serenity.maven.version>1.9.16</serenity.maven.version>
  <serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.7</serenity.cucumber.version>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

Comment: <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13-beta-2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
 
 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>

Comment: <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.7</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
  <version>${serenity.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
  <version>${serenity.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
  <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>serenity-screenplay</artifactId>
  <version>${serenity.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>serenity-screenplay-webdriver</artifactId>
  <version>${serenity.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
  <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
     
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>       
        <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>serenity-reports</id>

Comment: <id>serenity-reports</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>             
            <goals>
              <goal>aggregate</goal>                       
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

Comment: @sanju, please use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question rather than adding more information as comments, it will make it much easier to read and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Start with https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber-starter or https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber4-starter. Migrate your feature files into `src/test/resources/features` with an appropriate sub-directory structure. Then migrate your glue code and Page Objects across to the new project. If possible, use the Serenity WebDriver integration rather than a hand-coded one.

Comment: Thank you!, can i stick to webdriver hand coded instead?

Comment: After i do so, how can i generate the reports

Comment: Also, this is not a maven project, how can i run

Comment: I am looking for the piechart report from the test inside the starter pack. What is the name of that html?

Comment: I used verify in maven build and a index.html shows me a pie chart. Going forward i wanted to add my own runners, will that work?

Answer (score 0):

We can generate report using Allure just by little configuration. Check this [AllureSetup](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-maven) for Java-Cucumber-Maven framework

Add the following in your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <reportVersion>2.3.1</reportVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```